# Sharks in the water: Another user sabotaging your answer by downvoting and making false comment

Tags: discussion

Let's just say for example you answer a question that has 1-2 existing, but unaccepted answers. One of the answers is okay, but a sub-optimal solution. The OP is a newbie, so is looking w/o having great depth of knowledge yet. So, you post an answer, and the previous answerer down-votes your answer and posts a comment to cast doubt upon your answer. The comment is nonsense, but the OP wouldn't know. In a nutshell, it seems like this user purposely sabotaged my answer so he'd get the green check. The user's answer would work, so it would seem "right" but the method posted violates a key principle of the technology. Has this ever happened to anyone else? This type of crap behavior kind of puts me off SO at times.

Comment: Is your question just _Has this ever happened to anyone else?_? For me, no.

Comment: A discussion about what? That behavior? Whether we condemn it? How can we change it? How to deal with it?

Comment: I assume it would be condemned. I also assume there's not much to be done about it except vent, discuss. I don't know.

Comment: I had thought the 'discussion' tag means discussion, but maybe it means 'question' on meta. I don't know. Anyhow, @Makoto summed it up well, so I guess it is a thing that happens and you just have to do your best and wait for time to pass.

Comment: Just wait for a year or two of Google hits on the Q+A.  The truth shall emerge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you describe is better known as [The Slowest Cheater in the East](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/175248), and it's not a new phenomenon.

To overcome something like this, you have to understand that there are two things at play here:

- Answer acceptance is really something for the OP, and not for the community at large.  The community can decide which answer is best based on votes.
- If your answer is genuinely good, then don't worry about it getting a downvote.  Someone else in the community that reads this answer will likely agree with its quality and upvote it.

  Once you get more than one downvote, start considering how you answered the question again; you may have missed a few details.

The only time I'd worry about this is if the comment is directly insulting or rude; otherwise, treat it as constructive criticism and improve your own answer.  Don't worry about acceptance; if the community agrees with your answer, you can outscore the accepted answer.  There are even badges for that.